# Is it possible to decide matching percentage using code return by pl sql soundex function

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

Is it possible to decide matching percentage of two string 
using code return by soundex function of plsql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Soundex isn't terribly reliable for matching strings, especially once they are over a certain length, you might want to look into the UTL_MATCH package options.

You could use the Jaro-Winkler method in the UTL_MATCH package. There is a similar question on SO here:
[How can I use jaro-winkler to find the closest value in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3585246/how-can-i-use-jaro-winkler-to-find-the-closest-value-in-a-table)

The UTL_MATCH docs are here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e10577/u_match.htm

There is some good docs on matching strings here too: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/owb.112/e10935/match_merge.htm

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

The difference function converts two strings to their Soundex codes and then reports the number of matching code positions. Since Soundex codes have four characters, the result ranges from zero to four, with zero being no match and four being an exact match. (Thus, the function is misnamed — similarity would have been a better name.)

```
SELECT * FROM s WHERE difference(s.nm, 'john') > 2;
```